# Логистический алгоритм

Tags: алгоритм, php, html

Друзья, пришел посоветоваться с вами по поводу логистического алгоритма. 
У нас есть стеллажи, они пронумерованы по рядам, а в рядах по местам, пример на картинке.

Погрузчик выходит сверху с центра, это все равно откуда,  и ему дается около 5 точек, откуда надо забрать или выгрузить товар, надо как-то придумать алгоритм, что бы затрат на езду было как можно меньше.

Пока на ум приходят сети петри ...

[image]

Comment: В такие моменты я очень рад что учил дискретку :)

Comment: [Поиск_пути][1]


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8

Answer (score 2):

[Теория графов и Алгоритм Дейкстры](http://dtf.ru/articles/read.php?id=57085)

> В этой статье я расскажу о написании интеллекта, способного просто и эффективно передвигаться по игровой карте. Кому-то эта задача может показаться довольно тяжелой, но на самом деле ничего сложного здесь нет.

Answer (score 1):

Это должно тоже подойти [Задача Комивояжера](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0)